# Change the new material Progressbar rotation speed

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-5.0-lollipop

I don't seem to find a way to change the speed of the ProgressBar.
On devices with Kitkat and earlier the older ProgressBar is changing it's speed according to the `indeterminateDuration` attribut and it works. But on Lollipop, the new material ProgressBar is not being affected.
Do you know how it could be done?
Thanks!

Comment: This is not supported by the framework Material progress bar. You would need to implement your own progress animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my library [ProgressBarLP](https://github.com/akhilspillai/ProgressBarLP) for your purpose. You can change the duration of the animation through which you can increase or decrease its speed. The attribute to change would be `progressCycleDuration`. The support is only from API 11 though.